# Is this possible to create video from PDF files?

Tags: php, pdf, video, ffmpeg

I want to make video from pdf file.Is it possible?
I created video from images with ffmpeg but not
able to create video from PDF files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is script to convert pdf to video:

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 -resize 800x $pdf_path $temp_images");
exec("ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -framerate 0.5 -b 1800 -i $temp_images_wildcard -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -r 5 -t 22 -y $frame_target 2>&1",$output);
```

Comment: convert: missing an image filename

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your PDF files are in your working directory, to create a movie file from a set of PDF files you can execute:

```
exec("mogrify -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 -format png ./*.pdf")
exec("convert -delay 600 *.png movie.mp4")
```

This requires  [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)  and  [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to be installed. Works on Linux/Mac OS X/Microsoft Windows. Not vectorial.

---

If you want to generate some PDF files to test the commands, here is a python script that generates PDF files:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    np.random.seed(i)
    dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=50)
    print('dates: {0}'.format(dates))
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates), 1), index=dates.astype(str), columns=['A'])

    print('df: {0}'.format(df))
    plt.figure(figsize=(60,15))
    df.plot(y='A', use_index=True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=70)
    plt.savefig('plot_{0}.pdf'.format(i), dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

---

FYI:

- [Imagemagick Convert PDF to JPEG: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" / PDFDelegateFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32466112/395857) --> that's the error message you get if Ghostscript is not installed.
- [Convert every pdf in the current directory to png](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121293/16704) --> convert doesn't support batch conversion, unlike mogrify.
- ffmpeg requires the images to have some very specific naming convention, unlike convert which simply takes the lexicographical order.
- [Using Imagemagick to convert images to the video: background of the video is black, whereas the background of the pictures are white](https://superuser.com/q/1238852/116475)
- [How can I run mogrify over the 3 million JPG files?](https://superuser.com/q/745523/116475) -> mogrify can only process one file at the time, but one can go around with `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the PDF to images and then use your old method to produce the video

Answer (score 0):

Standard FPS (frames per second) in a video is around 30, that's why keeping it in usual document formats with regular paging is impractical. [There's a way](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-jpg-image/) to convert a pdf file into images, then you can use it in your video.