# how to convert scanned pdf to text using wand python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

While using Wand and imageMagick to convert a scanned PDF to text, I am getting the following error:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gibin/PycharmProjects/ML/Image_PDF/.ksldwjldf.py", line 28, in <module>
    Get_text_from_image(r"C:\Users\gibin\PycharmProjects\ML\Image_PDF\536676972_image.pdf")
  File "C:/Users/gibin/PycharmProjects/ML/Image_PDF/.ksldwjldf.py", line 13, in Get_text_from_image
    pdf=wi(filename=pdf_path,resolution=300)
  File "C:\Users\gibin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 8212, in __init__
    units=units)
  File "C:\Users\gibin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 8686, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "C:\Users\gibin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 240, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/GIBIN_~1./AppData/Local/Temp/magick-23476_sCYGtEq3gb-%d" "-fC:/Users/GIBIN_~1./AppData/Local/Temp/magick-234763X1vpsurlvH5" "-fC:/Users/GIBIN_~1./AppData/Local/Temp/magick-23476fUlS8Tr85dwk"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/459
```

Code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import gc

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\gibin\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
def Get_text_from_image(pdf_path):
    print(pdf_path)
    pdf=wi(filename=pdf_path,resolution=300)
    pdfImg=pdf.convert('jpeg')
    imgBlobs=[]
    extracted_text=[]
    for img in pdfImg.sequence:
        page=wi(image=img)
        imgBlobs.append(page.make_blob('jpeg'))
        print(len(imgBlobs))
    for imgBlob in imgBlobs:
        im=Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text=pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
        print(text)
        extracted_text.append(text)
    return ([i.replace("\n","") for i in extracted_text])
Get_text_from_image(r"C:\Users\gibin\PycharmProjects\ML\Image_PDF\536676972_image.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you check your input file exists and the temporary file indicated in error trace is really created ?

Comment: did you install ghostscript? is it in your path?

Comment: It's working now after adding ghostscript in path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine after installing GHOSTSCRIPT and adding it as an environment variable.
Download ghostscript from  [HERE](https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)

After that, you need to set the environment variable.
Add a new system variable:

Variable: GS_PROG

Value: Full path to the location of your gswin64c.exe file

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [Imagemagick Convert PDF to JPEG: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" / PDFDelegateFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466112/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-jpeg-failedtoexecutecommand-gswin32c-exe-pdfdel)?. 
Instead you can also use other methods to convert pdf to jpg images page wise. I have used pdf2img library to do that, if you are free to use any library then prefer using pdf2img.